# How to send the res1d file from view to controller in .net Framework 4.8?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

- 

This is my Html*

```
<div id="UploadFileModal" title=" Upload Files">
    <div class="form-row col-md-12">
        <div style="text-align:start" class="col-md-4">
            <label>Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem">
            <input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem" type="Date" id="dtUploadDate" name="UploadDate" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row col-md-12">
        <div style="text-align: start" class="col-md-4">
            <label>Select Run</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem">
            <select class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem" id="ddlUploadRun" name="UploadRun">
                <option value="0">-- Select Run --</option>
                <option value="R00">R00</option>
                <option value="R06">R06</option>
                <option value="R12">R12</option>
                <option value="R18">R18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row col-md-12">
        <div style="text-align: start" class="col-md-4">
            <label>Choose Excel File</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem" id="fileExcel" name="fileExcel" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row col-md-12">
        <div style="text-align: start" class="col-md-4">
            <label>Choose Result File</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem" id="fileResult" name="fileResult" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

- 

Thsi is ny js*

```
UploadResultFiles = () => {
    debugger;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('UploadDate', $("#dtUploadDate").val());
    formData.append('UploadRun', $("#ddlUploadRun").val());
    formData.append('fileExcel', $("#fileExcel")[0].files[0]);

    var fileResult = $("#fileResult")[0].files[0];
    formData.append('fileResult', fileResult);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessResultData", "Master")',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            $("#resultMessage").text("Data processed successfully.");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $("#resultMessage").text("Error processing data.");
        }
    });
}
```

This is My Controller Method

`public ActionResult ProcessResultData(DateTime UploadDate, string UploadRun, HttpPostedFileBase fileExcel, HttpPostedFileBase fileResult)`

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

public ActionResult ProcessResultData(DateTime UploadDate, string UploadRun, HttpPostedFileBase fileExcel, HttpPostedFileBase fileResult)*

**So how  can i send the .res1d file from view to controller in the fileresult**